# When shouldComponentUpdate / render is called for child components of updated component

Tags: reactjs

Having read a bunch of articles on the web about `shouldComponentUpdate` & `render` I want to double check if I get it correct when components are rerendered (`render` method is called) and when `shouldComponentUpdate` is called.

React docs (and dozens or articles say) that **`shouldComponentUpdate` is called ONLY when new props are received or there is new state**. But is seems that `PureComponent` does the same at first glance...

So to investigate it I wrote sample app:

- parent component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Hello from './Hello';

class App extends Component {

  objWithName = { name: 'World' };

  state = {
    date: Date.now()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ date: Date.now() });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Rendering timestamp {this.state.date}</p>
        <Hello name={this.objWithName} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

- child component

```js
import React from 'react';
export default class Hello extends React.Component {    
    
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate called');
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render called');
        return <p>Hello {this.props.name.name}</p>
    }
}
```

**So my first question is:** is it completely true? I mean: In above code snippets, parent component in `setInterval` calls `setState` just to trigger its update, but this state is not used anywhere. And after doing that, child component is rerendered (`render` is called) & `shouldComponentUpdate` is called even though nothing has changed for him (it didn't receive any new props, nor state). I didn't find any explanation for this behaviour in React docs so I'm not sure how it works. What is more, if that child component didn't have any input props at  (simply render static string) it would also get rerendered. Can sb explain it?

**So my second question is**: what does it mean new props/state is received by the component? Does it mean that object value is changed (for primitives simply new value, and for objects new reference)?

**Third thing**: assuming that a change in parent top most component (e.g. `App.js`) in the application happens (new prop or new state), does it mean that by default ALL react component that are currently rendered/mounted (even leafs that do not have any state, nor props that were changed) will rerender?

Comment: Pure component meaning stateless component. Which don't play with any life cycle method except render and also when you use PureComponent you don't actually modify the state. It works exactly like Pure function in javascript which just takes props and return JSX elements. Pure component does the job of shouldComponentUpdate method internally by doing shallow comparison

Comment: This is to your first question --> shouldComponent - by default this method gets called by returning true internally so irrespective of whether prop or state changes or not this method gets called. In your case it gets called like how it does internally

Answer (score 0):

1. `shouldComponentUpdate` is just called from `setState` and forces render when returns true (default behaviour) - and updating DOM when different. This is by design to have a lifecycle/flow. When `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false then you can avoid unnecessary, usually costly render processing (and DOM update). PureComponent is just an optimized, ready to use component with `shouldComponentUpdate` defined to shallowly compare props (by comparing references).

React doesn't care if props/state are used, not using observables - you can use mobx for that.

2. New props means any change - it's `shouldComponentUpdate` responsibility to check swallowly or deep, depends what you need.
3. Yes, all children will be updated (forced to refresh node state/view in virtual DOM). It's fast/optimized process (operating on virtual tree) but they should use `shouldComponentUpdate` to limit theirs rerendering (and final DOM updates).